# Spring Session JDBC 1.2.0 in Spring Boot 1.3.5

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, spring-session

when I use the spring session starter for spring boot 1.3.5 and set the version for spring session to 1.2 it comes to conflicts. Seems that it is not compatible and I have to wait for boot 1.4. OK...

To get it running I just added a dependency to spring session 1.2, without the starter and added a class which extends `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`. 
This works when I run it in an external tomcat but not when I run it in the embedded tomcat of boot 1.3.5.

Can I use SS 1.20 in SB 1.3.5?

Thank you

**One step forward**

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(auth == null || !(auth.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetailsImpl)) 
        return null; 
    ...
```

Here is always null returned although auth.getPrincipal() is an instance of UserDetailsImpl. 
Seems to be a classloader issue.
But why does it work in an external tomcat? Any other classloading strategies here?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by _spring session starter_ since Spring Boot does not (yet) offer a starter module for Spring Session.

Comment: Sorry, it was starter-jdbc, as mentioned here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes, you can use Spring Session 1.2.x with Spring Boot 1.3.x without any problems.

Spring Session project contains [many samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples) to help users get started with Spring Session (documentation on these samples is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#samples)). Among these samples is also one that resembles your use case - [Boot JDBC sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/httpsession-jdbc-boot).

As shown in the samples and the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#httpsession-jdbc) you should use `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` annotation to bootstrap Spring Session JDBC support. If your app by any chance also uses Redis, you should exclude the `SessionAutoConfiguration` provided by Spring Boot 1.3 since your combination of dependencies will trigger the auto-configuration of Redis-backed Spring Session, which is something you don't want if you'd like to use JDBC-backed session store.

Comment: I used this doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-boot.html. When I add these dependencies the annotation @EnableJdbcHttpSession is missing, since the whole session-jdbc jar is missing. When I add the whole spring-session 1.2 dependency, not only session-jdbc then everything is there but it works not in embedded tomcat. In the example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.2.0.RELEASE/samples/httpsession-jdbc-boot I cannot see any dependency to spring session, but ok, I have no clue how gradle works...

Comment: My understanding is: Add the dependency to session-jdbc, add a @EnableJdbcHttpSession and it should work out of the box.

Comment: Can you please put together a sample that reproduces your problem and share it using Github? Also please note that the artifact id `spring-session-jdbc` and not `session-jdbc`.

Comment: Another thing - are you by any chance adding dependencies to the project manually, rather than relying on Maven or Gradle to provide dependency management? If so, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/569) reported against Spring Session recently.